# ASP .NET Crystal report generation form Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, crystal-reports

This may be a common question but I found a lot but didn't get any answer that helps me. I am new to ASP .NET development. So excuse me if the question looks silly.

As I am new I just took a simple Database for this task. I've 2 table in the database. `name_table` and `value_table`. My .dbml file looks like this:

[image]

I got a crystal report viewer in my .aspx file. I write a query for getting the data from database. The query works fine. This is the query:

```
DataClasses1DataContext dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var query = from name_table in dataContext.name_tables select name_table.name;
```

This is my database expert view of crystal report.

[image]

My problem is I want to populate the result of query to crystal report. For Crystal Report Data source I am using a DataSet. Waiting for helps.. :)

Comment: CR uses TYPED DataSets (generally xml as source). So you need to convert your linq to dataset (Typed).

Answer (score 0):

As i comment :

CR uses TYPED DataSets (generally xml as source). So you need to convert your linq to dataset (Typed).

**Generally this is one way to convert linq anonymous type result to datatable.**

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link.

According to the following link here is an example

```
 DataTable getAllWorkingDays = getdata();
 var days = from d in getAllWorkingDays.AsEnumerable()
                       where Convert.ToBoolean(d["isWorkDay"]) == true
                       select new
                       {
                           dt = d["dt"],
                           isWorkDay = d["isWorkDay"]
                       };

            getAllWorkingDays = CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods.CopyToDataTable(days);
```

Comment: Can you show me how to convert linq to dataset? I searched for that with no luck before posting the question.

Comment: @Rashad have check the link?

Comment: @Rashad  your pro9blem is how to convert convert linq anonymous type result to datatable. Try to do the posted way. I have been using this way for years.

Comment: >> Can you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365015/crystal-report-using-linq-query-result

Comment: Just a function which fill my datatable. In your case you could just : DataTable dt = CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods.CopyToDataTable(query);

Comment: I really can't figure out where to put these classes. :(

Comment: My friend i think you have to study more .net framework :). Just add them to your project. Be careful the namespaces.

Comment: Yes I know I have o study. But actually I am a iOS developer. I have to make a .Net application.

Comment: Just create 2 classes. One CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods and the other ObjectShredder under the same namespace.

Comment: now in this line values[_ordinalMap[p.Name]] = p.GetValue(instance, null); of ObjectShredder shows Parameter count mismatch.