# Crystal Report using linq query result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, crystal-reports

My database:

[image]

My linq query:

```
DataClasses1DataContext dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var query = (from name_table in dataContext.name_tables select name_table.name).ToList();
            CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(query);
```

My crystal report settings:

[image]

.aspx page:

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
<CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
<Report FileName="DailyAttendenceRepoort.rpt">
</Report>
</CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

.aspx.cs click event:

```
DataClasses1DataContext dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var query = (from name_table in dataContext.name_tables select name_table.name).ToList();
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(query);
```

**Result:** Nothing shows.

**Question:** Why the report is not displaying anything?

Comment: I think it is logic. Your crystal report datasource is an xml(DataTable1) and the xsd and you set just an anonymous type. As a said before you query must have Type of DataTable1. To do that you have to use the classes i have refereed to.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to implement your process.

Comment: Initially try, with the way i have post, to create a datatable from query.

Comment: I havent used CR for a while now. Did you try using `Refresh` method of the report? this is juist a hunch

Comment: @Nilesh >> I tried. Its giving this: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It seems that the `List` object is not recognized in this context. CAn you Convert this list into a datatable and then assign it as a datasource and check if its working? I found one post which mentions how to set the datasource to a list. Something like this `ReportDocument.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(yourlist );`